# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing defs: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, anaconda, h5py

I have installed h5py using `conda install h5py`. However, when I `import h5py` the above error is given. This is the whole error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "training.py", line 12, in <module>
    import h5py
  File "C:\Users\colin\anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from . import version
  File "C:\Users\colin\anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\h5py\version.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import h5 as _h5
  File "h5py\h5.pyx", line 1, in init h5py.h5
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing defs: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Thanks.

Comment: You _**should**_ be able to `import h5py` in an conda environment. I can replicate your error if I try to import when I'm not.  How are you running Python? conda environments include any of: 1) Spyder or IDLE IDE, 2) an "Anaconda Prompt" command window, or 3) for standard Windows Command Prompt, run conda's `activate.bat` script in the Scripts folder. I don't work with other IDEs, but am sure they can also be configured to work with the conda distro.

Comment: The problem occurs also in proper conda environment (with h5py=3.6.0 and hdf5=1.10.6)

Answer (score 1):

I tried different combinations of `h5py` and `hdf5` versions even the most recent. None of them worked for me. So I did the following and it helped me:

- uninstalled both the `h5py` and `hdf5` (`conda uninstall`)
- pip install `h5py` (not `conda install`)

So I left off with only `h5py` within the conda environment.

Even thought it has some drawbacks as **takluyver** mentions in his post: https://github.com/conda-forge/h5py-feedstock/issues/103#issuecomment-1017537370

> The wheel package (what you get with pip) bundles libhdf5 into the wheel, so it should never  have a mismatch between the HDF5 used to build h5py and the HDF5 it finds at runtime. That approach has its downsides, though - e.g. the read-only S3 driver is enabled in conda-forge, but not in pip, because that would mean bundling more libraries.

Comment: When I run `conda uninstall h5py` it also suggests uninstalling Tensorflow (and thus Keras). When I run `conda uninstall hdf5` it removes the hdf5 spec, but it re-installs h5py with a wrong version of hdf5 again. This is a dead end for me.

Comment: @GeneM: do `conda uninstall h5py --force` to prevent it uninstalling TensorFlow. And in my case I still had issues so I followed it with `pip uninstall h5py`.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is limited to the `h5py`/`hdf5` combination from the `conda-forge` channel specifically.

Khamyl pointed to the correct open `conda-forge` issue: https://github.com/conda-forge/h5py-feedstock/issues/103 (it is still open as of the time of this writing).

However, there is no need to uninstall anything or to switch from the `conda` package manager.

Just downgrade to the latest `h5py` version available from the `pkgs/main` channel, e.g.:

```
conda install h5py=3.6.0 -c pkgs/main
```

This will downgrade `hdf5` to the compatible version from the default channel as well.

Comment: Encountered this error trying to install scanpy on a windows machine (python 3.9), this suggestion resolved for me

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter the same error.

So first use

```
pip uninstall h5py
```

Building h5py also requires several Python packages, but in most cases pip will automatically install these in a build environment for you, so you don’t need to deal with them manually.

then install again but using

```
pip install --no-binary=h5py h5py
```

Then restart the kernal.

For more details https://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/build.html